# Is $\sum_{n= 2}^\infty \frac{a_n}{n!}$ a rational number?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory

I'm solving a problem which boils down to check whether the following number $x$ is rational or not.

> Let $$x = \sum_{n= 2}^\infty \frac{a_n}{n!}$$ where $a_n \in \mathbb N$ and $0 \le a_n < n$. Moreover, there are infinitely many $a_n \neq 0$.

I want to do it by myself, but I wonder if this is a big question that requires too advanced number theory.

I would like to ask if it can be solved just with elementary group, ring, or field theory. Thank you so much!

---

**Update:** I forgot to mention that $x < 1$.

Comment: Think about the case where all $a_n$ equal $1$.

Comment: Note: The best characterisation of the rationals is probably that they have periodic decimal expansions.

Comment: @Angina the case $a_n=1$ all $n$ shows the sum is not always rational, but there's still a question whether it's *ever* rational.

Comment: @GerryMyerson If $a_n = 1$ for all $n$, then $x = e-1$ is not rational. Do I miss something?

Comment: Good, do you know **why** $e$ is irrational? @LAD

Comment: @AnginaSeng I found the proof [here](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Proof_that_e_is_irrational). Actually, I'm trying to modify it to fit my case.

Comment: Aha! Please let us know if that works! @LAD

Comment: That's what I said, LAD: the case $a_n=1$ for all $n$ shows that the sum is NOT ALWAYS rational.

Comment: Aha @GerryMyerson I misread *rational* and *irrational* :)) Now I got your point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum_2^{\infty}{n-1\over n!}=\sum_2^{\infty}\left({n\over n!}-{1\over n!}\right)=\sum_2^{\infty}{1\over(n-1)!}-\sum_2^{\infty}{1\over n!}=\sum_1^{\infty}{1\over n!}-\sum_2^{\infty}{1\over n!}=1$$ so it is possible for the sum to be rational. But (as noted in the comments) it is also possible for the sum to be irrational.

Comment: I've just figured out that I miss the condition $x<1$. As such, this rules out the case $a_n = n-1$.

Comment: OP asked a solution with "group, ring or field theory" ...??

Comment: I'm sure you can modify the first few terms to meet that condition. Try it!

Comment: @nilo OP wanted a solution with *elementary* group, ring or field theory. I gave an even more elementary solution. Why complicate matters with abstract algebra, when arithmetic will do?